# Typescript error "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, openapi-generator

I have a react app using typescript, and one of my dependencies is a custom github repo called `dexcane-common`. I recently updated the `dexcane-common` repository to use the `typescript-axios` openapi client generator where before it was using the `typescript-fetch` openapi client generator. Now when I run `yarn start`, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:12)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| 
> import type { Configuration } from './configuration';
| import type { AxiosPromise, AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';
| import globalAxios from 'axios';
    at ./node_modules/dexcane-common/api.ts (index.css:22:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./node_modules/dexcane-common/index.ts (index.css:22:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/SignupForm.tsx (Login.tsx:51:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

The typescript versions in my `dexcane-common` and my react app project matches. Has anyone seen this error before, with an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example